# How to use SubArray inside a structure?

Tags: julia

I have some structure with an array and it's subarray.

I've tested some subarrays with view() function to see their type naming and used it to pass an empty value of that type the constructor, but that didn't work:

```
mutable struct SomeType{T<:Real}
    A::Array{T,1}
    subA::SubArray{T,1,Array{T,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true} 
    # using subA::SubArray solved the problem - ?

    SomeType{T}(len) where T<:Real = new(
        Array{T,1}(len),
        SubArray{T,1,Array{T,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true} 
        # doesn't work as well: view(Int[1,2,3], 1:3)
        )
end
```

Trying to create an object throws an error:

`MethodError: Cannot convert an object of type SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true} to an object of type SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true}`

Until I comment-out braces for SubArray type declaration in the structure field and change the constructor to:

```
function SomeType{T}(len) where T<:Real
    A = Array{T,1}(len)
    subA = view(A, 1:len)
    new(A, subA)
end
```

Although the problem is solved, I do not clearly understand:

1. If I pass empty parametric {T} SubArray initialization to a constructor, it doesn't work — why?
2. How to declare SubArray type for objects that do not change their size after creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Understanding the error and fixing the constructor

Your second version of the constructor is the correct one. The problem with the first one is that `S = SubArray{T,1,Array{T,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true}` is a *type* not an *instance*: it has type `Type{S}`, whereas what you really want is an object with type `S`. That's exactly what's being created with that call to `view`.

You'd have exactly the same problem if you tried to pass `Array{T,1}` as your first argument, rather than `Array{T,1}(len)`. The second of these creates an actual array, the first is the type itself.

### Improving the type declaration

Julia allows you to be both flexible and concrete about the type of your subarray, and it makes sense to exploit this in your definition of `SomeType`:

```
mutable struct SomeType{T<:Real, S<:SubArray{T,1}}
    A::Vector{T}
    subA::S
end
```

Any instance will have a specific type for `S`, allowing Julia to emit efficient code for working with this object. But using this way of defining your type allows you to support different types of `SubArray`: ones created with different parent array types, ones created with `UnitRange` indices and ones with `StepRange` indices, etc.

You can of course be even more general and say `S<:AbstractVector{T}`, which would include your `SubArray` as a special case. Again, any instance will have concrete type, so this extra generality doesn't cost you anything in terms of performance. The more specific declaration is preferable only when it represents a convenient way of enforcing something you're relying on.